# Create sub-objects within wizard

Tags: popup, wizard, multi-step

**Question:**
*In a 'Create new' wizard, what is a good way to create sub-object?*

I will have a wizard to create an object, *Item*.
An *Item* will always belong to another object, *Group*.
A *Group* will in itself belong to yet another object, *Container*.

The `Group` and `Container` are simple objects with just a Name and Description. But the `Item` is the main object and is more complex. It will probably require multiple Wizard pages.

Now I need to create a wizard to create this item, including a *Group* if not using one already existing. Example screenshot:

[image: Example of wizard]

These are the alternatives that I've been considering. None of them seem desirable to me.

**Alternative 1:**
Instead of the "Create new group" option in the drop-down, add a link to open a "Create new Group" dialog popup window on top of the wizard.
This dialog would in itself have a "Create new Container" link that would pop up a "Create new Container" dialog on top.

**Alternative 2:**
Like the screenshot, creating a new Group will simply be a choice in a drop-down. Making this choice will take you to *Step 2* of the wizard once you click *Next step*, otherwise skipping directly to *Step 4*.
The same method is used in *Step 2* where you select container.

**Alternative 3:**
If selecting *Create new group* in the drop-down, new option will appear below with a slide animation, containing *Group name*, *Group desc*, and *Group container*.
If *Create new container* is selected, yet another slide animation will reveal *Container name* and *Container desc*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself like a pop-up in this situation.

[image]
Leads to this pop-up...

[image]
Note, I place "Create new group" lastly in dropdown list. Now the trick is to add yet another pop-up for the New Container. It should be no problem to have the three panels open at once.
You could use an expanding pop-up to reduce clutter.

[image]
Expands to...

[image]
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the input! Yes, I guess in a way having three dialog panels could be handled, but I find it looking a bit 'unprofessional' somehow. But your suggested combination of Alt1 (for Group) and Alt3 (for Container) could work out well. I'll try it!